# primefaces dataTable not rendered with tabChangeListener

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable, tabview

I have tabView,which includes two tab, and two data table.When first tab selected,first datatable will be shown,second tab selected then second datatable will be shown. But my datatable can not see the rendered changes.

Here is my xhtml;

```
<p:tabView id="tabViewKullanici" dynamic="true">  
<p:ajax  event="tabChange" listener="#{userBean.onTabChange}" update=":userForm:userDataTable,:userForm:userDataTable2"/>  

<p:tab title="#{etiketler.userinfo1}" id="userinfoList1"  > 
</p:tab>

<p:tab title="#{etiketler.userinfo2}" id="userInfoList2">
</p:tab>
</p:tabView>

 <p:dataTable id="userDataTable" rendered="#{userBean.tabIndex eq 1}"/>
<p:dataTable id="userDataTable2" rendered="#{userBean.tabIndex eq 2}"/>
```

And here part of userBean.java

```
private int tabIndex;

@PostConstruct
    public void init() { tabIndex = 1; }

 public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Tab Changed");  
        System.out.println("event.getTab().getId(): " + event.getTab().getId());
        System.out.println("event.getTab().getTitle(): " + event.getTab().getTitle());
        if((event.getTab().getId()).equals("userinfoList1") ){

            tabIndex = 1;
       }
        if((event.getTab().getId()).equals("userinfoList2") ){

            tabIndex = 2;
      }

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }

   public int getTabIndex() {
        return tabIndex;
    }

    public void setTabIndex(int tabIndex) {
        this.tabIndex = tabIndex;
    }
```

Comment: Ajax rendering doesn't work that way. If the datatable started of with `rendered="false"`, the way you're attempting to rerender it, it'll never be shown. What you should do is `update="tabViewKullanici"` in the ajax listener

Comment: Thanks for reply. I defined the boolean tabIndex in userBean.java. And my xhml page is the same then it works succesfully.